# Why is there a jump in my sidebar animation?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am having problems with the sidebar not opening smoothly. It seems that the width of the column changes as it is opened and there is a choppy jump.

I have tried applying transitions to the CSS and using flex-grow / shrink. The transitions did nothing and flex grow made the column too big.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-secondary">
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row d-flex vh-100 flex-nowrap flex-grow-1">
      <div class="col-auto px-0 bg-dark" id="navigation">
        <div id="sidebar" class="collapse collapse-horizontal">
          <div class="show align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white border-end h-100">
            <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-1 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
              <span class="fs-5">OEP</span>
            </a>
            <hr />
            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
                  <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i>
                  <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#submenu1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                  <i class="fs-4 bi-collection"></i>
                  <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Display</span>
                </a>
                <div id="submenu1" class="collapse" style="transition: 0.75s">
                  <ul class="collapse show nav flex-column ms-1" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                    <li>
                      <a href="{% url 'dataAcquisition' %}" class="nav-link px-0">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Data Acquisition</span
                          >
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="w-100">
                        <a href="{% url 'psiList' %}" class="nav-link px-0">
                          <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">PSI List</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="{% url 'psiRange' %}" class="nav-link px-0">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">PSI Range</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="{% url 'psiAccuracy' %}" class="nav-link px-0">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">PSI Accuracy</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="{% url 'setupScreens' %}" class="nav-link px-0">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Setup Screens</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="nav-link px-0">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Checkloads</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="{% url 'loadData' %}" class="nav-link px-0">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Load Data</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col ps-md-2 p-0 color-primary position-relative" style="overflow-x: hidden" id="adjustable-col">
        <div class="row align-items-center bg-dark" style="height: 58px">
          <div class="col-1">
            <button href="#" data-bs-target="#sidebar" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-outline-light shadow-none ms-2 bi-list"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button Group">
              <a class="btn btn-outline-light shadow-none" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#connectionsModal">
                <span class="button-text pe-2 border-end">Connections</span>
                <i class="bi-circle-fill text-danger ps-2 pe-2" id="cap-conn"></i>
                <i class="bi-circle-fill text-danger pe-2" id="producer-conn"></i>
                <i class="bi-circle-fill text-danger" id="consumer-conn"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="connectionsModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="connections" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content bg-dark">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title text-light" id="connections">
                      Connections
                    </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                      <div class="table-resonsive">
                        <table class="table table-dark rounded rounded-3 overflow-hidden table-hover">
                          <thead style="position: sticky; top: 0">
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="col">Server</th>
                              <th scope="col">Client</th>
                              <th scope="col">Protocol</th>
                              <th scope="col">Status</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <th colspan="4" class="border-0 headerBorder"></th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>CAP</td>
                              <td>OEP Data Server</td>
                              <td>TCP</td>
                              <td class="bi-circle-fill text-danger" id="cap-conn-model"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>OEP Data Server</td>
                              <td>RabbitMQ</td>
                              <td>TCP</td>
                              <td class="bi-circle-fill text-danger" id="producer-conn-model"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>RabbitMQ</td>
                              <td>OEP Web Sever</td>
                              <td>TCP</td>
                              <td class="bi-circle-fill text-danger" id="consumer-conn-model"></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end text-light">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col">WA</div>
              <div class="col">
                <input class="form-control-sm me-2" style="width: 100px" id="wa" readonly />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-4">{% block content %} {% endblock %}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The animation jump is caused by ambiguity in width calculation. This can be the result of padding or margin on critical elements, and flexbox can also contribute. There are many ways to solve the problem by moving those properties elsewhere.

In this case I moved the padding and set the element with padding to inline-block display. Note that I also moved your border class to one of the full-height elements. I'd assume that was desirable.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-secondary">
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row d-flex vh-100 flex-nowrap flex-grow-1">
      <div class="col-auto px-0 bg-dark border-end" id="navigation">
        <div id="sidebar" class="collapse collapse-horizontal">
          <div class="d-inline-block px-3 pt-2 align-items-center align-items-sm-start text-white">
            <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-1 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
              <span class="fs-5">OEP</span>
            </a>

            <hr />

            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
                  <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i>
                  <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#submenu1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                  <i class="fs-4 bi-collection"></i>
                  <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Display</span>
                </a>
                <div id="submenu1" class="collapse" style="transition: 0.75s">
                  <ul class="collapse show nav flex-column ms-1" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                    <li>
                      <a href="{% url 'dataAcquisition' %}" class="nav-link px-0">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Data Acquisition</span
                          >
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="w-100">
                        <a href="{% url 'psiList' %}" class="nav-link px-0">
                          <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">PSI List</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="{% url 'psiRange' %}" class="nav-link px-0">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">PSI Range</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="{% url 'psiAccuracy' %}" class="nav-link px-0">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">PSI Accuracy</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="{% url 'setupScreens' %}" class="nav-link px-0">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Setup Screens</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="nav-link px-0">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Checkloads</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="{% url 'loadData' %}" class="nav-link px-0">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Load Data</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col ps-md-2 p-0 color-primary position-relative" style="overflow-x: hidden" id="adjustable-col">
        <div class="row align-items-center bg-dark" style="height: 58px">
          <div class="col-1">
            <button href="#" data-bs-target="#sidebar" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-outline-light shadow-none ms-2 bi-list"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button Group">
              <a class="btn btn-outline-light shadow-none" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#connectionsModal">
                <span class="button-text pe-2 border-end">Connections</span>
                <i class="bi-circle-fill text-danger ps-2 pe-2" id="cap-conn"></i>
                <i class="bi-circle-fill text-danger pe-2" id="producer-conn"></i>
                <i class="bi-circle-fill text-danger" id="consumer-conn"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="connectionsModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="connections" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content bg-dark">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title text-light" id="connections">
                      Connections
                    </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                      <div class="table-resonsive">
                        <table class="table table-dark rounded rounded-3 overflow-hidden table-hover">
                          <thead style="position: sticky; top: 0">
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="col">Server</th>
                              <th scope="col">Client</th>
                              <th scope="col">Protocol</th>
                              <th scope="col">Status</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <th colspan="4" class="border-0 headerBorder"></th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>CAP</td>
                              <td>OEP Data Server</td>
                              <td>TCP</td>
                              <td class="bi-circle-fill text-danger" id="cap-conn-model"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>OEP Data Server</td>
                              <td>RabbitMQ</td>
                              <td>TCP</td>
                              <td class="bi-circle-fill text-danger" id="producer-conn-model"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>RabbitMQ</td>
                              <td>OEP Web Sever</td>
                              <td>TCP</td>
                              <td class="bi-circle-fill text-danger" id="consumer-conn-model"></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end text-light">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col">WA</div>
              <div class="col">
                <input class="form-control-sm me-2" style="width: 100px" id="wa" readonly />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-4">{% block content %} {% endblock %}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```